# Access ListView Checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to figure out how to modify the state on a checkbox that is embedded in a ListView/GridView.  The problem is that the checkbox is dependent upon the approval status of some records in a separate DataGrid. (eg. I am using the checkbox as an approval status True = all approved, False = none, null = some approved).

Since the DataContext is an Entity it doesn't have a bool value that I could use to handle it.

```
<ListView x:Name="EmployeeNameListBox" Height="330" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectionChanged="EmployeeNameListBoxSelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False" >                           
            <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsThreeState="True" Checked="EmployeeCheckBoxChecked" Unchecked="EmployeeCheckBoxChecked" x:Name="CheckBoxHero"/>                                                  
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1} - {2}">
                                    <Binding Path="LastName" />
                                    <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                                    <Binding Path="EmployeeNumber" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Here is where I'm trying to update the approval status:

```
foreach (var employee in this.employees)
{
    var records = from a in this.dailyActivities where a.Employee == employee select a;

    var approvedRecords = from r in records where r.IsApproved == true select r;

    if (approvedRecords.Count() == 0)
    {
        // None Approved checkbox state = false
    }
    else if (approvedRecords.Count() == records.Count())
    {
         // All Approved checkbox state = true
    }
    else
    {
         // Some Approved Set Checkbox state to null
    }                
}
```

Comment: Silverlight ? WPF ? Add more Tags please

Comment: If it doesn't have a bool value, why not create a wrapper object (call it viewmodel perhaps) and bind to a value in that class instead?

Comment: I ultimately just went with implementing the variable in another partial class.  Seems to be working alright, I was just trying to avoid the partial class since I only needed it for this one control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Nullable bool (bool?)` wrapper property in your ViewModel class (I am assuming you are using MVVM pattern) and simply bind your checkbox with that property using `RelativeSource`.

Put your logic in `getter` of that property -

```
public bool? IsRecordApproved
{
  get
  {
     .....
     // Your logic here
  }
}
```

And whenever you want the property to be updated on your UI, raise property changed event on your property. (`INotifyProeprtyChanged` event should be implemented by your ViewModel class)